# Does Eclipse do a binary-compatibility-check of jars as they are added to a project?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, dependency-management

While I was singing the praises of Maven's dependency management, an Eclipse user told me (an IntelliJ user) they don't need stuff like that because any time they add a jar to a project Eclipse will test it's binary compatibility against other jars in the project.

Is this true? Is this Eclipse itself or a plugin?
Is there similar functionality available in IntelliJ/Netbeans?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a thing in neither Eclipse nor in Maven (you'd need something like the [maven-clirr-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/clirr-maven-plugin/) to do something approaching).

Comment: Given your SO standing, I'm going to accept "I'm not aware of such a thing" to be fact. You get the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just did the following:

1. Install Eclipse
2. Create new Project
3. Add a library that is missing dependencies.
4. Create a class that does something like `System.out.println(com.library.AClass.class);`
5. Note that Eclipse does not complain.
6. Run it and get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when the class is loaded.

This tells me dependency checks don't (always) happen.